# Detect remote administration tool (rat)

Tags: keyloggers, rat

I suspect being the victim of a hacking attack. What steps should I take to ensure that no rat software is running on my computer?

I checked the autostart by executing `initctl list` but im not sure if this is alright:

```
indicator-application start/running, process 2557
unicast-local-avahi stop/waiting
update-notifier-crash stop/waiting
upstart-udev-bridge start/running, process 2304
update-notifier-hp-firmware stop/waiting
xsession-init stop/waiting
dbus start/running, process 2315
no-pinentry-gnome3 stop/waiting
update-notifier-cds stop/waiting
gnome-keyring-ssh stop/waiting
gnome-session (Unity) start/running, process 2502
ssh-agent stop/waiting
unity7 start/running, process 2702
upstart-dbus-session-bridge start/running, process 2435
gpg-agent start/running
indicator-messages start/running, process 2535
logrotate stop/waiting
indicator-bluetooth start/running, process 2536
unity-panel-service start/running, process 2520
hud start/running, process 2491
im-config start/running
unity-gtk-module stop/waiting
session-migration stop/waiting
upstart-dbus-system-bridge start/running, process 2432
at-spi2-registryd start/running, process 2501
indicator-power start/running, process 2537
update-notifier-release stop/waiting
indicator-datetime start/running, process 2540
indicator-keyboard start/running, process 2543
unity-settings-daemon start/running, process 2493
indicator-sound start/running, process 2544
upstart-file-bridge start/running, process 2438
bamfdaemon start/running, process 2423
gnome-keyring stop/waiting
window-stack-bridge start/running, process 2327
indicator-printers start/running, process 2546
re-exec stop/waiting
upstart-event-bridge stop/waiting
unity-panel-service-lockscreen stop/waiting
indicator-session start/running, process 2547
```

Especially im wondering about `ssh-agent stop/waiting` and `session-migration stop/waiting`

What else can I check to ensure there is no one connected to my machine?

Here is the full output of `netstat -ap`: http://pasteall.org/468969

**Snippet:**

```
Aktive Internetverbindungen (Server und stehende Verbindungen)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:microsoft-ds          *:*                     LISTEN      1556/smbd       
tcp        0      0 localhost:6942          *:*                     LISTEN      3587/java       
tcp        0      0 *:902                   *:*                     LISTEN      1454/vmware-authdla
tcp        0      0 *:netbios-ssn           *:*                     LISTEN      1556/smbd       
tcp        0      0 localhost:63342         *:*                     LISTEN      3587/java       
tcp      104      0 172.25.20.1:49752       172.25.255:microsoft-ds VERBUNDEN   13165/gvfsd-smb 
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN      3296/httpd      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:4444               [::]:*                  LISTEN      3480/java       
tcp6       0      0 [::]:microsoft-ds       [::]:*                  LISTEN      1556/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 [::]:902                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1454/vmware-authdla
tcp6       0      0 [::]:mysql              [::]:*                  LISTEN      3280/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:netbios-ssn        [::]:*                  LISTEN      1556/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      3296/httpd      
udp        0      0 *:ipp                   *:*                                 3893/cups-browsed
udp        0      0 *:8976                  *:*                                 3587/java       
udp        0      0 *:54067                 *:*                                 1113/avahi-daemon: 
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                                 1113/avahi-daemon: 
udp        0      0 *:36345                 *:*                                 3587/java       
udp        0      0 172.25.255.2:netbios-ns *:*                                 1538/nmbd       
udp        0      0 172.25.20.1:netbios-ns  *:*                                 1538/nmbd       
udp        0      0 *:netbios-ns            *:*                                 1538/nmbd       
udp        0      0 172.25.255.:netbios-dgm *:*                                 1538/nmbd       
udp        0      0 172.25.20.1:netbios-dgm *:*                                 1538/nmbd       
udp        0      0 *:netbios-dgm           *:*                                 1538/nmbd       
udp6       0      0 [::]:53859              [::]:*                              1113/avahi-daemon: 
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                              1113/avahi-daemon:
```

Comment: `sudo netstat -ap > network_stats.txt`

Answer (score 3):

If you believe your machine is compromised, there is essentially nothing you can do on that machine to ensure it is not.

You can route all traffic from that machine trough a trustworthy machine and analyse that, or you can reinstall the OS and all software on the compromised machine.